# Enable App Mesh integration in Terraform for AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: terraform, integration, aws-fargate, mesh-network

I did a lot of struggle in google and not finding any solution, I am finally reaching out to you for help. I recently extensively worked and completed infra code to deploy a couple of microservices to Fargate. Everything went well. But I have got stuck at this point "Enable App Mesh integration".  I have attached an image to understand better where I am having this problem. I googled a lot but not getting a solution to enable App Mesh in Terraform.

Though, I can code for "Enable proxy configuration". But this is not enough, I need to enable App Mesh as well. Please share the piece of Terraform code if you have one to enable it.

[image]

Comment: But have you created your mesh app using its own [resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appmesh_mesh)?

Comment: Yes, I have created it.

resource "aws_appmesh_mesh" "mesh" {
    name = "my_mesh"
    spec {
      egress_filter {
        type = "ALLOW_ALL"
      }
    }
}

Comment: I finally figured it out. I imported the working ECS deployment with Terraform and made changes to the imported code to suite my requirement.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out:-) Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hi @Sandy could you please share your solution?